# Custom content negociation handling extension AND "Accept" header with Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have this resource (simplified):

```
@Path("/cars{extension:(\\.(xml|json))?}")
public class Cars {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response searchCars(@PathParam("extension") String extension) {
        System.out.println("extension: " + extension);
        //...
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

And I want, for instance (but the business logic can change), to return an xml response if the extension is xml, or Json if the extension is json, whatever the header "Accept" is.
The thing is by default I want to use the Accept header but let's say some dummy guy wants to access my web service with Ajax and doesn't know much about headers, I want to make things easy for him by just adding the appropriate extension.
With that snippet I am able to get the extension (if there is one) but I don't know how to change the strategy accordingly.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
So I found something, I can use .type() from Response.ResponseBuilder like:

```
Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(200).entity(output);
if ([some test about extention or header])
    responseBuilder.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
// other tests
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to do, but that would mean I need to handle it for all the paths...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `ContainerResponseFilter` for this, so you don't have todo it for each path.

First check for extension - aka the MediaType the *dummy guy* loves to get.

Than check if requested MediaType is acceptable for your service. If not, I would say the *dummy guy* has hard luck ;)

Example code *[jersey 2.x]*:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class EntityResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter( ContainerRequestContext reqc , ContainerResponseContext resc ) throws IOException {
        MediaType mediaType = this.getMediaTypeFromExtentionOrHeader(); // TODO
        List<MediaType> mediaTypes = reqc.getAcceptableMediaTypes();
        if( mediaTypes.contains(mediaType) ) {   
            resc.setEntity( resc.getEntity(), new Annotation[0], mediaType );
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Hope this was helpful somehow :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. By the way "Dummy guy" is not pejorative ;-) So, it works with a filter, I had it working with a parent class handling that stuff for my resources though. One question about the filter and ContainerResponseContext, just for performance matter I would like to be sure that setEntity() is not called after the entity has been serialized a first time (after the call to the resource)? Do you know? To be more clear, I want to be sure that no serialization/marshalling happens before the filter.

Comment: Marshalling is one of the last things jersey will do.  So first filters, than marshalling, ...